# Search encrypted text with 'like' in Room Database

Tags: kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room, typeconverter

In my Room Database i have an entity MessageDto with the body field to be Encrypted. To achieve that i use the TypeConverters like below.

```
@Entity(tableName = "messages")
data class MessageDto(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "message_id")
    var messageId: Long,

    @TypeConverters(EncryptString.Converter::class)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "body", defaultValue = "")
    var body: EncryptString

.....
```

As you can see the body is type of EncryptString which is a class that turns the String to another String.

```
class EncryptString(var value: String = "") {
    class Converter {
        @TypeConverter
        fun decrypt(encrypted: String): EncryptString {
            return EncryptString(encrypted.toDecrypt())
        }

        @TypeConverter
        fun encrypt(decrypted: EncryptString): String {
            return decrypted.value.toEncrypt()
        }
    }
}
```

So now i want to make a select query and use the "like" function of Sql upon the messages.body field.

When i run the below query i dont get any results although i know that the text exists in the body as EncryptString

```
@Query("Select body from messages where body like :text")
fun searchMessage(text: String): List<EncryptString>
```

What do i do wrong...?

Comment: any luck ?? i m stuck here too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your Dao method in following form:

```kotlin
@Query("Select body from messages where body like :text")
fun searchMessage(text: EncryptString): List<EncryptString>
```

Just Change input argument type from `String` to `EncryptString`